# Unable to run magento on a virtual machine

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.6, mysql5

I'm setting up a VM to work on magento.

I set up correctly the webserver (apache2), PHP, mysql like I did on other server where I got magento working, but this time it doesn't want to run...

All I'm getting is this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lex/code/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1229 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lex/code/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1229 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lex/code/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1229 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lex/code/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1241 Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in /home/lex/code/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 151
```

Unfortunatly I'm not able to fix it using suggestions found on the net (changing file permissions, and so on). The files are under my local directory, but I set up the group owner to be www-data.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and Magento 1.6.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: magento is just a PHP script. It couldn't care less if it's on a physical or virtual machine. What's on the indicated lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I finally got it.
It was a missing configuration...

maybe the guys at magento team should expect everything to fail and print some useful message... at least bootstrapping the application.

I think I'll make some sort of patch for this...

Comment: you could share what config you are missing, it might help others

Comment: Glad you finally got it. So.. what was it?

Comment: This worked for me http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/ , problem is a dependency which isnt there!